# 2 or more threads at the same time in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm doing a javaFX animation and I did the following class:

```
public class Visual extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    private static final int JFXPANEL_WIDTH_INT = 360;
    private static final int JFXPANEL_HEIGHT_INT = 550;
    private static JFXPanel fxContainer;
    private static Train train;
    private static AtomicBoolean running;

    public Visual(Train t) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);//new thread start
        thread.start();
        running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        train = t;

        this.setSize(new Dimension(JFXPANEL_WIDTH_INT, JFXPANEL_HEIGHT_INT));
        this.setTitle(train.getId());
        this.setResizable(false);

        fxContainer = new JFXPanel();
        fxContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(JFXPANEL_WIDTH_INT, JFXPANEL_HEIGHT_INT));
        add(fxContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(exitListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (train.getRoute() == null && running.get()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        while (running.get()) {
            createScene(train);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                //Logger.logException(ex, "");
            }
        }
    }

    private static int nbSectors = 0;

    private void createScene(Train t) {
        if (t.getRoute() != null) {

            nbSectors = 0;

            for (Block s : t.getRoute().getBlocks()) {
                nbSectors += s.getSectors().size();
            }
            System.out.println("number of sectors : " + t.getId());

            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 550, Color.ALICEBLUE);

            Line l = new Line(100, 70, 100, 450);

            l.setStrokeWidth(4);
            l.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);

            int nbStations = t.getLine().stations.size() - 1;

            int m = 0;
            boolean skipped = false;
            for (Block b : t.getRoute().getBlocks()) {
                for (Sector s : b.getSectors()) {
                    if (s.isOccupied()) {
                        root.getChildren().add(new Circle(100, 70 + m * (380. / nbSectors), 20, Color.RED));
                        skipped = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (skipped) {
                        break;
                    }
                    m++;
                }
                m++;
            }

            int i = 0;
            // System.out.println("nb de lignes : "+nbLines);
            for (Station station : t.getLine().stations) {
                root.getChildren().add(new Text(130, 70 + i * (380 / nbStations), station.getId()));

                root.getChildren().add(new Circle(100, 70 + i * (380 / nbStations), 10, Color.BLACK));
                i++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < nbSectors; j++) {
                root.getChildren().add(new Line(95, 70 + j * (380 / nbSectors), 105, 70 + j * (380 / nbSectors)));
            }

            root.getChildren().add(l);

            fxContainer.setScene(scene);
        }

    }

    public final void stop() {
        running.set(false);
    }

    WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            stop();

        }
    };
}
```

Everything works pretty well when in my GUI I do one `new Visual(greenTrain)`, for example. The issue appears when I start multiple windows of visual. There are no errors in the terminal but only the last Visual instance created runs. The others before just do nothing. And i don't understand why, cause each one should be in a different thread, no?.

thanks for helping ;)

Comment: I don't think there's enough code to know exactly why you get the behavior you describe; however you cannot modify the UI from a background thread. So at a minimum, `fxContainer.setScene(scene)` should be executed on the FX Application Thread, using `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: `javax.swing.JFrame` with javafx ? You are mixing Swing and javaFX. Not sure how the GUI Threads are coexisting in that case.

Comment: so i should add pltaform.runlater inside run?

Comment: yeah AxelH is a bit weird i know

Comment: Yes, just wrap the UI code (not the `Thread.sleep(..)`, obviously) in `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: I have the same problem... it doesn't work in paralel